# GORM/SQL query to ignore invalid utf-8 characters

Tags: utf-8, orm, psql, go-gorm

I'm using GORM to query a database with rows containing invalid utf8 characters and getting errors when comparing values:

`db.Where("name ILIKE ?", value)`

`ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xc6 0x61 (SQLSTATE 22021)`

I've tried filtering out possible non utf8 characters by preceding my call with statements like these with no luck:

`db.Where("name !~ ?", "[^\\\\x00-\\\\x7F]")`

`db.Where("octet_length(name) = char_length(name)")`

`db.Where("length(name) = length(encode(decode(name, 'escape'), 'escape'))")`

`db.Where("name not ILIKE '%[^%]%'")`

Is there any way to filter out all rows with fields that are not utf8?

I can't fix the rows in the database because there is a constant flow of data coming in at the moment that could also be not utf8. For now, I just want to ignore those rows. Does anyone know the answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone runs into the same issue with attempting to perform an ILIKE query in a database with non utf8 values. I was able to find a workaround by using

> db.Where("LOWER(name) LIKE ?", strings.ToLower(value))

It seems that LIKE does not have the same issues with non UTF8 characters as ILIKE does.